# Mask the created by field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to mask the created by field value in SharePoint discussion board list. Tried the power shell script way `$SPlist.ShowUser=$false`. But this is taking out the functionality for replying to the discussion board. I am looking for a JavaScript solution to mask the value by the script below.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){

        $('.ms-subtleLink').text('***');

})

</script>
```

Question:

1. Is there a better way to mask the value?
2. Created by field is shown for few seconds and the javascript is invoked later to replace the value. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you using 2013?

Answer (score 0):

if you use JSlink you can specify your own rendering template (in Javascript). This will solve point 2.

[This example uses color coding, but the idea is the same](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please point me to some examples?

Comment: I've added a link to an example. I'd happy to write a complete masking example for you tommorow, if you want.